# How keep macro with \csname from gobbling up starred argument?

Tags: macros, starred-version

For purposes more involved than what's shown here, I want to test certain commands having both an ordinary form and a starred form, with the latter constructed using the `suffix` package. To do that, I pass each form as argument into a macro `\try` that involves a `\csname`...`\endcsname` expression.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{suffix}

\newcommand{\toward}{\rightarrow}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\toward*{\Rightarrow}

\newcommand{\try}[1]{$a \csname#1\endcsname b$}

\begin{document}

OK: $a \toward b$ and $a \toward* b$

OK---\verb!\try{toward}! works: \try{toward}

BAD--\verb!\try{toward*}! gobbles up the arrow: \try{toward*}

\end{document}
```

As shown below, the result of `a \Rightarrow b` disappears from the output of `\try{toward*}`

How can that be fixed?

[image: Unwanted gobbling up of starred form of argument]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `\toward*` is *two* tokens, not one, but `\csname toward*\endcsname` only builds *one* token.

You can emulate `\csname...\endcsname` with `\scantokens`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{suffix}

\newcommand{\toward}{\rightarrow}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\toward*{\Rightarrow}

\makeatletter
\edef\bschar{\expandafter\@gobble\string\\}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\try}[1]{%
  $a%
  \scantokens\expandafter{\bschar#1}%
  b$%
}

\begin{document}

OK: $a \toward b$ and $a \toward* b$

OK---\verb!\try{toward}! works: \try{toward}

OK---\verb!\try{toward*}! gobbles up the arrow: \try{toward*}

\end{document}
```

A different solution that provides for an expandable `\try` and also avoids `suffix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\toward}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\Rightarrow}{\rightarrow}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\try}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF
   { \str_range:nnn { #1 } { -1 } { -1 } } % get the last character
   { * }
   { $ a \use:c { \str_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { -2 } } * b $ }
   { $ a \use:c { #1 } b $ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

OK: $a \toward b$ and $a \toward* b$

OK---\verb!\try{toward}! works: \try{toward}

OK---\verb!\try{toward*}! works: \try{toward*}

\end{document}
```

The argument to `\try` is stringified and examined: if the last item in the string is `*`, then we detach it and put after the command.

[image]

Comment: maybe simpler if OP defined its `\try` to itself have a starred variant so `\try{toward}` vs `\try*{toward}`,  the latter testing effect of `\toward*`.

Comment: @jfbu I guess that the OP wants to show the effect of some macros with the minimum effort.

Comment: (off-topic) a bit disappointing that `suffix` package allows only single token suffixes

Comment: Although this method complicates the code for `\try`, it localizes the additional work there rather than requiring (as in @Werner's answer ) additional definitions for the commands to be fed as arguments to`\try`. Thank you both for the solution and the straightforward explanation of what was wrong.

Comment: @egreg: Whare at the advantages of the method that uses `xparse` instead of `suffix`? (It looks like  using `xparse` would involve learning & applying a whole little additional syntax & semantics.)

Comment: @murray Because `xparse` is a more modern an maintained package, whereas `suffix` is basically a collection of clever hacks.

Answer (score 4):

The result of `\try{toward*}` disappears because there is not command `\csname toward*\endcsname`. And `\csname...\endcsname` for an undefined command turns into `\relax` (which prints nothing).

If you want to use `\try{toward*}` but also have `\toward*` work as a regular *starred* macro, then you can just define `\csname toward*\endcsname` to be the same as `\toward*` (or `\Rightarrow`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{suffix}

\newcommand{\toward}{\rightarrow}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\toward*{\Rightarrow}% This defines \toward to have a starred version
\expandafter\newcommand\csname toward*\endcsname{\Rightarrow}% This defines \towards* ...
                                                             % ... which is different 
                                                             % from what is defined above

\newcommand{\try}[1]{$a \csname#1\endcsname b$}

\begin{document}

OK: $a \toward b$ and $a \toward* b$

OK---\verb!\try{toward}! works: \try{toward}

OK--\verb!\try{toward*}! gobbles up the arrow: \try{toward*}

\end{document}
```

---

Something related from [The TeXbook](http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/texbook.pdf) (p 40):

> ... you can go from a list of character tokens to a control sequence by
>   saying '`\csname<tokens>\endcsname`'. The tokens that appear in this construction between `\csname` and `\endcsname` may include other control sequences, as long as those control sequences ultimately expand into characters instead of TeX primitives; the final characters can be of any category, not necessarily letters. For example, '`\csname TeX\endcsname`' is essentially the same as '`\TeX`'; but '`\csname\TeX\endcsname`' is illegal, because `\TeX` expands into tokens containing the `\kern` primitive. Furthermore, '`\csname\string\TeX\endcsname`' will produce the unusual control sequence '`\\TeX`', *i.e.*, the token `\TeX`, which you can't ordinarily write.

Comment: This method works just fine. Its only drawback is that it requires additional coding for each starred command to be fed as argument to `\try`. (In the actual application, the `\try` takes multiple arguments, several of which have both ordinary and starred forms.)

Comment: I especially appreciate the explanation that `\csname...\endcsname` for an undefined command turns into `\relax`.

Comment: Be aware that the undefined command is turned into `\relax` only within the current scope. This assignment is restricted to the global scope even when the `\globaldefs`-parameter has a positive value.

Answer (score 1):

In case you wish to do without eTeX and it is only about single trailing stars as suffixes, I can offer a macro `\UD@SplitTrailingStar`.

Syntax: `\UD@SplitTrailingStar{⟨sequence⟩}{⟨prepend⟩}{⟨append⟩}`

In case `⟨sequence⟩` doesn't have a star as last token yields:
`⟨prepend⟩⟨sequence⟩⟨append⟩`

In case `⟨sequence⟩` does have a star as last token yields:
`⟨prepend⟩⟨sequence without the last star⟩⟨append⟩*`

`⟨prepend⟩` can, e.g., be `\csname`.

`⟨append⟩` can, e.g., be `\endcsname`.

Due to `\romannumeral`-expansion, the result is delivered after two expansion-steps.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{suffix}

\makeatletter
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Paraphernalia
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@SplitTrailingStarLoop{<sequence>*}{}{}{<prepend>}{<append>}
%% In case <sequence> doesn't have a star as last token yields: 
%%   <prepend><sequence><append>
%% In case <sequence> does have a star as last token yields: 
%%   <prepend><sequence without the last star><append>*
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@GobbleToExclam{}\long\def\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!{}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@gobbletostar{}\long\def\UD@gobbletostar#1*{}%
\newcommand\UD@keeptostar{}\long\def\UD@keeptostar#1*{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@RemoveStarDelimitedTillUD@nil{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveStarDelimitedTillUD@nil#1*#2\UD@nil{#1*}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstStarDelimitedLoop[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbletostar#1}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
   \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter}%
   \UD@keeptostar#1}{ #2}}%
  {%
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstStarDelimitedLoop
    \expandafter{\UD@RemoveStarDelimitedTillUD@nil#1}{#2}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@starfork{}\long\def\UD@starfork#1!!*!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@SplitTrailingStarLoop[5]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam{#1}{%
    \UD@starfork!#1!*!{\UD@firstoftwo{#4#2#5}}% #1 empty.
                !!#1!{\UD@firstoftwo{#4#2#5*}}% #1 single star.
                !!*!{\UD@secondoftwo{}}%
   !!!!%
  }{\UD@secondoftwo{}}{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral0\UD@ExtractFirstStarDelimitedLoop{.#1\UD@nil}{}}{#2#3}}}%
    {\expandafter\UD@SplitTrailingStarLoop
     \expandafter{\UD@gobbletostar#1}}%
    {*}{#4}{#5}%  
  }%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@SplitTrailingStar{<sequence>}{<prepend>}{<append>}
%% In case <sequence> doesn't have a star as last token yields: 
%%   <prepend><sequence><append>
%% In case <sequence> does have a star as last token yields: 
%%   <prepend><sequence without the last star><append>*
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral-expansion, the result is delivered after two 
%% expansion-steps.
%% \UD@SplitTrailingStar is a wrapper for \UD@SplitTrailingStarLoop.
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@SplitTrailingStar[2]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@SplitTrailingStarLoop{#1*}{}{}{ #2}%
}%

\newcommand{\try}[1]{$a\UD@SplitTrailingStar{#1}{\csname}{\endcsname}b$}%

\newcommand{\toward}{\rightarrow}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\toward*{\Rightarrow}

\makeatother    

\parskip=\baselineskip
\parindent=0ex

\begin{document}

\verb!$a\csname toward\endcsname b$!: $a\csname toward\endcsname b$

\verb!$a\csname toward\endcsname*b$!: $a\csname toward\endcsname*b$

\verb!\try{toward}!: \try{toward}

\verb!\try{toward*}!: \try{toward*}

\hrulefill

% something more complex:

\makeatletter
\newcommand\name{}\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%
\makeatother

\name\newcommand{*{ma}*ny**star}{\rightarrow}
\name\WithSuffix\newcommand{*{ma}*ny**star}*{\Rightarrow}

\verb!$a\csname*{ma}*ny**star\endcsname b$!: $a\csname*{ma}*ny**star\endcsname b$

\verb!$a\csname*{ma}*ny**star\endcsname*b$!: $a\csname*{ma}*ny**star\endcsname*b$

\verb!\try{*{ma}*ny**star}!: \try{*{ma}*ny**star}

\verb!\try{*{ma}*ny**star*}!: \try{*{ma}*ny**star*}

\hrulefill

\name\newcommand{*{mo}*re**stars*}{\rightarrow}
\name\WithSuffix\newcommand{*{mo}*re**stars*}*{\Rightarrow}

\verb!$a\csname*{mo}*re**stars*\endcsname b$!: $a\csname*{mo}*re**stars*\endcsname b$

\verb!$a\csname*{mo}*re**stars*\endcsname*b$!: $a\csname*{mo}*re**stars*\endcsname*b$

\verb!\try{*{mo}*re**stars**}!: \try{*{mo}*re**stars**}

But Problem:

\verb!\try{*{mo}*re**stars*}!: \try{*{mo}*re**stars*}

Reason:

\verb|\UD@SplitTrailingStarLoop| cannot "know" that this time the trailing star should not be treated as
a suffix but as a part of the macro-name.

\verb!\try{*{mo}*re**stars*}!\\
yields:\\
\verb!$a\csname*{mo}*re**stars\endcsname*b$!\\
while the control-word-token \verb|\*{mo}*re**stars| at the time of performing \verb|\csname|-expansion
is undefined and thus within the current scope gets assigned the meaning of the \verb|\relax|-primitive.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This approach seems evidently more complicated (at least to the extent that the complication of methods using `suffix` or `xparse` don't just hide such complication inside their packages).

Comment: The approach might seem complicated because it  involves **expandable** checking without introducing forbidden "sentinel tokens" and without whatsoever TeX-extensions whether the last token inside a macro-argument is a star `*` while due to `\csname..\endcsname` control-sequence-tokens' names can contain several stars which implies the need of expandably detecting the last one if present without loosing surrounding curly braces if present...